# Possible workaround to have multiple http get methods two actions with same name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-get, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am using asp.net MVC 4. Is there a way to use two http get methods on an action with the same name but different parameters? Or just a way to have the page be an index page for both so the name of the page is consistent? Also, int cannot be null.

Example:

Used for querystring and searches

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int num, string aString)
   {
   }
```

Used for just an action link click(a default search)

```
 [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Index()
 {
 }
```

Comment: Why would you even need this kind of scenario? If it was any use, I guess MS would provide some kind of capacity to run it this way.

Comment: yeah its uncommon situation but that's  per requirements, I think its not best also, maybe I could change the teams mind. good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No work-around. What you can do is following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int num, string aString)
{
      //if num == null, throw exception or do something
      // if string == null, do something, if not, do something else
}
```

Comment: It smiles like hack ... What would be the use case for this? To get model in get?

Comment: What if I need the int to not be null, but nothing is pass when you click a link.

Comment: @Ray: It's default behaviour. All 3 parameters are optional, then you check which once are missing and decide what to do.

Comment: @Peter: yes, model is weird but possible, but general behavior is valid. You can have 2-3 optional parameters in query string: '/action?num=1', '/action?astring=name' or '/action?num=1&astring=name'. This is all usual web use case.

Comment: @Ray: you can make private method with overloads and decide which overload you wanna call.

Comment: @Nenad sure it is valid, but not always what is valid is also make sense. ;) But it the end is all about the reasons behind ...

Comment: Yeah, @PeterStegnar I ended up changing things a bit. It's best that a model not be used in this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (Html . BeginForm ( "ViewName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get ) {
   Html . Hidden ( "actionname1", "true" ) form elements set 1 submit
   button 1 }

   (Html . BeginForm ( "ViewName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get ) {
   Html . Hidden("actionname2", "true") form elements set 2 submit
   button 2 }

   In Controller, check for "true "values for actionname1, actionname2
   and decide on control flow for each. Assumption: Same View and Same
   Controller WITH Two distinct FormMethod.Gets

   ..Paurav
```

Answer (score 0):

What I actually end up doing was passing in an object with nullable values in one get http request action. As @Display Name suggested above in the comment Microsoft has this functionality built into the .net framework.